# How do you render div objects from non-React libraries in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found a library I want to use in my project, but it's a plain JavaScript library and doesn't know anything about React.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-formatter-js

Is it possible to use this in my React project? I tried this, but the render crashes.

```
class JSONView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const formatter = new JSONFormatter(this.props.data);
        const Rendered = formatter.render();

        return (
            <div>
                <Rendered />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The error I get is this.

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

The `typeof Rendered` is `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the library returns `HTMLDOMElement` from function `formatter.render()`.

**So you can't use JSX syntax to render it.**

While I agree that  the other answers can work, I would prefer using a dom `ref` and appending the returned `HTMLDOMElement` from `formatter.render()` in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import JSONFormatter from "json-formatter-js";
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class JSONView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    ref = null;

    componentDidMount(){
      const formatter = new JSONFormatter(this.props.data);
      const Rendered = formatter.render();
      this.ref.appendChild(Rendered);
    }

    render() {     
        return (
            <div ref={e => this.ref = e}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<JSONView data={{Hello: {Hello:  "World"}}} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qmkgru) You can drill down to the object.

In the other approach which makes use of **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** or **just rendering the string content**, you have the risk of losing DOM events.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import JSONFormatter from "json-formatter-js";
import Hello from './Hello';

class JSONView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    ref = null;

    render() {     
        const formatter = new JSONFormatter(this.props.data);
          console.log(formatter);
          const Rendered = formatter.render();
          console.log(Rendered.innerHTML);

          return (
            <div>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:Rendered.innerHTML}} />
            </div>
          );
    }
}

render(<JSONView data={{Hello: {Hello:  "World"}}} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Working Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nfxphj) You cannot drill down to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class JSONView extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    public refs:{
        JsonDiv: HTMLDivElement;
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        const formatter = new JSONFormatter(this.props.data);
        this.refs.JsonDiv.appendChild(formatter.render());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref='JsonDiv'>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

or this one

```
class JSONView extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const formatter = new JSONFormatter(this.props.data);
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={formatter.render()}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

try

```
{ Rendered }
```

there might be warning if it ships class with html tags.

between curly braces {} and it'll work (99 %) and if it doesn't then continue reading.

---

you can render if it returns string.

currently it might b returning html object which is incompatible with react dom render.

if it contains class property then it'll cause problem even if it's in string format.

you can use **react-html-parser** to render html strings in react. [reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

```
const Rendered = formatter.render().outerHTML   // this will give you html string instead of html object
```

now use **react-html-parser** if you don't wanna manage class attribute name conflict as react accepts className

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';


class JSONView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const formatter = new JSONFormatter(this.props.data);
        const Rendered = formatter.render().outerHTML;

        return (
            <div>
               { ReactHtmlParser(Rendered) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```